# cutting part of the string

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, sed, grep

can some one explain me how to cut some string with using linux features like sed.
For example I have sting

```
THIS-some-string-zzz-55.xml
```

how to cut ".xml" ?

result should be like:

```
THIS-some-string-zzz-55
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo "THIS-some-string-zzz-55.xml" | sed 's/\.xml$//'
```

Answer (score 5):

A few ways:

```
 basename thisfile.xml .xml
```

basename is it's own executable, so you can call it from a shell script or exec it from C or a scripting language.

If your shell is bash:

```
FILE=filename.xml
echo “filename: ${file%.*}”
echo “extension: ${file##*.}”
```

..and finally with sed

```
echo "filename.xml" | sed 's/\.xml$//'
```

That '$' in the regular expressin in sed will make the .xml match only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`Grep` time

```
$> echo THIS-some-string-zzz-55.xml | grep -o -P "(.*)(?=\.xml)"
THIS-some-string-zzz-55
```

Grep have a magic -P flag

```
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.   This  is  highly
          experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

Btw, here is a useful [table](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html), where you can find positive lookahead `(?=*)`, that I'm using here.

Answer (score 0):

Does Bash count as a Linux feature?

If so, this might work for you:

```
# string="THIS-some-string-zzz-55.xml"
# echo ${string%.xml}
THIS-some-string-zzz-55
```

or in this case:

```
# echo ${string%.*}
THIS-some-string-zzz-55
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for explanation.